Validating Form Field in IOS
I have imported as below:
import SwiftValidator

Below is my ViewController class:
class OriginShipmentViewController: BaseViewController, OriginShipmentView {
     let validator = Validator()
}

You can see that I have initialised validator
Below is the button save click code:
buttonSave?.configureAppearance(
        appearance.mainButtonAppearance, title: localizedKey(key: "origin.next"))
    buttonSave?.addTargetClosure(closure: {_ in
        self.onclickSave()
    })

So you can notice ther is a method call named self.onclickSave() which is as below:
func onclickSave() {
    validator.validate(self)
}

Here, on this line : validator.validate(self) I am getting compile time error as below:

No exact matches in call to instance method 'validate'

What might be the issue? Thanks in advance.

What is the method signature of your validate() method?

You need to look into the library SwiftValidator and figure out how to use it. You may try the Xcode's quick help, and you should have a swift package or a framework and there is possibly a repo on GitHub or elsewhere which may have additional documentation. You may find a  README.md file in the swift package (if any) which should be a start.

@Pratik  public func validate(_ delegate:ValidationDelegate) and public func validate(_ callback:(_ errors:[(Validatable, ValidationError)])->Void) -> Void {

You have not conformed ValidationDelegate yet. By default, this protocol requires two functions validationSuccessful and validationFailed. Try to put these lines of code:
extension OriginShipmentViewController: ValidationDelegate {
    func validationSuccessful() {
        //TODO: 
    }
    
    func validationFailed(_ errors: [(Validatable, ValidationError)]) {
        //TODO: 
    }
}


Jordar my Son! its working
